# Copying database backup files from aws to on-premises datacenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a VPN connection between AWS VPC and Data center, running SQL Instance in private Subnet. What are the best / cost effective ways to copy backup database files from AWS EC2 Instance to a server running in on-premise data center.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for best instead of cost-effective, As data is important part of any application of organization.

I will prefer s3 with private repo and enable encryption at s3. There are several reasons of s3, some of them

- You can keep versioning of your DB backup
- Able to share with different centre
- Able to push notification on SNS when new DB backuped to S3.
- Very little chance of failure or data loss
- Pull New Database real time

[image]

So if you want to go for cost-effective then I think SCP will work or you can explore [copy-database](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/copy-database.html) .